# After update VS2012 project won't compile, SQLite not installed error

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, versioning

When I fired up Visual Studio this morning, it informed me of a couple of updates to install: the 
VS feedback tool, and SQLite. I installed both, and restarted VS 2012.

But then a "funny" thing happened on the way to compilation of my project: With "SQLite for Windows Runtime 3.7.14.1" still referenced in my project, I got an err msg that SQLite 3.7.14.1 was not installed. Okay, so I removed it from the references, and added a reference to "SQLite for Windows Runtime 3.7.15.1"

Yet, I still got that same err msg after that. What??? So I removed 3.7.15.1, adding no reference 
back, and now my project compiles. But my project does use SQLite - how is that happening?

In my Reference Manager list, three "SQLite for Windows Runtime" versions are available:

```
3.7.14.1
3.7.15
-and
3.7.15.1
```

In the immortal words of Vince Lombardi, "What in tarnation is going on here?!?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the latest SQLite version installed is 3.7.15.2, and I was trying to reference 3.7.15.1, which no longer exists on my machine. Once I got the latest from the "Extensions" tab of the References (instead of trying to select the penultimate version from the "Recent" tab), it compiled fine.